# How does free will relate to external determination?

Tags: philosophy-of-mind, free-will

Many believe free will is having the ability to make your own choices without outside influence. But everything you see, hear and smell is an outside influence. Every lesson learnt through past experience is an outside influence. Advertisers have learnt how to subliminally alter our choices without us even being aware of it. How can we ever trust that our decisions have not been influenced?

Comment: Can you change the title, and edit the question so that it is more amenable to an objective answer? Debate questions and opinion based answers are against the Philosophy SE policy.

Comment: As written, this is a thoroughly opinion-based question. Can you make clearer what the question is that you are having about philosophy?

Comment: @virmaior I had no problem to answer this question, hopefully in an objective way :-) Of course the title contains the banned words "your opinion". But I think we should not disencourage new participants with their serious questions by being overly formal.

Comment: It's not the words in the title that make this a poor question. Please tell me the question about philosophy you discern from the body of the question. The vast majority of it does not seem related to your answer.

Comment: @virmaior The question asks for the borderline between free will and external determination, notably whether these two concepts are contradictory.

Comment: @JoWehler if you can solve the problems with a question by editing (without making significant changes), do so and answer after that. If you can't, don't answer but close the question.

Comment: Thanks Jo. But don't bother. They obviously don't grasp the intention and thereby rob those who do the opportunity to give their input. A pity though as I was looking forward to reading other opinions.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1) Free will - according to a libertarian view - is defined by the following criteria:

- *Liberty*: Under identical conditions it would be possible to decide or act in a different way than one actually did.
- *Intelligibility*: The actor can explain and show the reasons why he decided and acted as he did.
- *Authorship*: It is the person in question who decides and acts. The person is not forced.

Advocates of free will differ how strict they interpret these criteria. The contra-position to a *libertarian* view is a *deterministic* view. Our subjective and conscious experience conforms to a libertarian view. But the only scientific view (neuroscience), which I consider to have the ability to explain the phenomenon, is a deterministic one.

For the whole issue see e.g., *Walter, Henrik: Neurophilosophy of Free will.* (2001)

2)  Of course we are influenced by outside factors. Most of all we are influenced by our previous experiences with our fellow men and with the physical world. In a given situation we do not just react to external stimuli. Instead our reactions depend also on our internal state. The latter is determined by what we have learnt and experienced.

Being totally independent in our decisions would not mean to *decide* but to play at dice (*random choice*).

Comment: Don't answer questions that should be closed.

Comment: Does random exist? Or is random just an incomplete knowledge of the precipitating conditions which lead to an event/occurrence?

Comment: @Zane Scheepers According to quantum mechanics the behaviour of certain microphysical objects is at random (radioactive decay of an atomic nucleus). And this randomness is not due to our incomplete knowledge but an objective property.

Comment: @ZaneScheepers Jo's answer is misleading in that he omits compatiblism, as well as Roger Penrose's answer to the problems you mention. See [this answer I posted](http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/a/30090/13808) to a previous question for the details.

Comment: @Alexander S King Why misleading? I get the impression that's Penrose thoughts concerning an wayout form determinsim - similar to Eccles' - are not accepted by the maiority of neuoscientists. Are his thoughts more than pure speculation? Note, that Penrose is not a trained neuroscientist. His eminent reputation is from mathematics and physics.

Comment: @Alexander S King My statement favouring determinism as heuristic in neuroscience derives from an essay of Thomas Goschke, a German psychologist working in neuroscience. He writes (my translation): “To study by experimental means those processes which lay at the base of voluntary actions, is meaningful only under the assumption, that these processes depend also in a systematic way on causal conditions.”  Goschke characterizes his position as compatibilistic. I have no problem in taking over this notation.

Comment: @JoWehler the definition you give of freewill ignores the distinction between compatibilist freewill and libertarian freewill. Roger Penrose has been mentioned in most discussions and lectures on freewill I have seen. If the OP wants to know what the current discussions about freewill are, he should be made aware of the above points, even if you don't agree with them.

Comment: Thanks Alexander. I look forward to reading up on the matter.

Comment: You walk into your house and find your wife in bed with another man. You either shoot him or walk out. Our first instinct would be to kill him. It's a basic, instinctive response. Taking the higher path is a higher brain function. The difference between the two is having the mental ability not to let your subconscious overpower your conscious mind. This is not something you are born with. It is developed and not everyone develops it. Things and people you are exposed to either enhance or inhibit it's development. It's my belief that at any given moment when it comes to choices we have only one